# ¿Cómo se diría en español "lovey"? (transitional object for children)

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término

> A **lovey** is a transitional object that comforts your child in your absence, and it can be especially valuable to a child when falling asleep [...] A soft toy or a small blanket that can be held closely can give your child a sense of security.
>
> <sub>(Elizabeth Pantley, "The no-cry sleep solution for toddlers and preschoolers")</sub>

Un *lovey* es uno de eso objetos que los niños de llevan a dormir (y a veces a todas partes), por lo general peluches, manitas y muñecas. Por razones de seguridad, se evita que estos tengan piezas pequeñas y/o partes afiladas o duras y por razones obvias, cuanto más suave el objeto mejor, para que el niño duerma abrazado al *lovey* y este no moleste en la cama.

Lo más típico es que dicho objeto sea un *peluche* o una mantita, pero este *"comfort object"* puede ser muchas otras cosas (cualquiera de los otros juguetes del niño, [piezas de puzle](http://www.babysleepsite.com/sleep-training/baby-lovey-how-when-why/), etc. )

¿Existe un nombre en español para estos objetos que los niños se llevan a dormir y que sirven para darles seguridad y reconfortarles?

Comment: Interesante pregunta, como padre me intriga la respuesta, a ver si puedo investigar algo.

Comment: Sí es cierto que no tiene que ser animal de peluche, pero el peluche es lo más común, y francamente yo trataría de entrenar al niño a usar un peluche así, porque creo que sería más eficaz a largo plazo por lo blando.  Analizándolo, es a fin de cuentas un sustituto de la leche materna, ¿no? y entonces es conveniente usar algo con una textura parecida.  Claro que durante el periodo de entrenamiento hay que seguir las tendencias naturales del niño, así que si lo que funciona al principio es un cochecito, bueno pues, a dormir con cochecito. // ¿Buscas una palabra para usar con el niño, ...

Comment: o con otro adulto?  Para el niño, yo diría *peluche*, o el nombre del peluche especial.  Ejemplo: llegamos al hotel a la hora de dormir del pequeño.  No hay tiempo para desempacar todo bien bien, pero sí hay que sacar *el peluche* de la maleta en seguida. // Si lo que quieres hacer es explicar el concepto a tu compañero de trabajo, entonces dependiendo de tu relación con él, podrías decir: objeto de transición, sustituto del seno, osito de peluche, peluche personal, peluche para dormir, objeto de cariño.  Supongo que se podría acortar y decir "cariño" nomás, que es lo que "lovey" quiere decir.

Comment: Por cierto "lovey" no es universal para esto en inglés, por lo menos en EEUU. // Tip: conviene hacer un poco de rotación de peluches para que no haya un gran desastre si el peluche mágico y único se pierde.  Mis hijos tenían uno principal y uno secundario.  Viajábamos con el secundario y el principal se quedaba en casa.

Comment: I agree with @aparente001 about the lack of universality here. In English as spoken in south-east England a lovey is a slightly derogatory term for an actor, presumably from their habit of over-using terms of endearment.

Comment: True (and interesting, btw), but the question is giving the necessary context and the [tag:solicitud-de-término] is for a Spanish word(s). The interesting part is when the Spanish term is not "universal". We have been suggesting the use of list community wiki answers for those cases in which there are equally valid "En mi país se dice así" answers.

Comment: @Diego - I love that type of Q & A too.  I wonder if waiting to bestow the green checkmark might encourage a larger variety of answers?

Comment: @aparente001, [I wonder that myself too](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2669/5481). I believe I left plenty of my own questions without a mark (other are still waiting for a better answer) because I wanted to encourage participation. I believe that it actually doesn matter that much, but I could be wrong...

Comment: @walen, completamente de acuerdo. De las 3 respuestas que la pregunta tiene ahora, una (dudú) parece aceptarse solo en España y la otra (tuto) parece recoger varios significados fuera de Chile. Cierto que los padres no van a usar "objeto transicional", pero se van a ver obligados a usar "manita, muñeco, etc." La mejor respuesta sería de hecho tu sugerencia de ver la propia traducción del libro en español y aún así padres y "libros para padres" pueden usar distintos términos. Aceptaré la respuesta de Gustavson hasta que alguien la mejore con algo más universal o la traducción que use el libro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acabo de consultar, físicamente, la edición española del libro en una librería que había por aquí, y la palabra que usa es:

[image: fotaza]

> **[amuleto](http://dle.rae.es/?id=2SuyWSo)**
>
> Del lat. amulētum.
>   1. m. Objeto pequeño que se lleva encima, al que se atribuye la virtud de alejar el mal o propiciar el bien.

Answer (score 5):

La traducción está en la propia definición: "objeto transicional".

Éste es el término utilizado en psicoanálisis: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objeto_transicional

> Un **objeto transicional** es un objeto material en el cual un infante deposita cierto apego, es por ejemplo un muñeco de peluche o un trapo [...] que tiene funciones psicológicas importantes, sobre todo al pretender dormir []. Constituye una fuente de placer y de *seguridad* para el infante que suele apretarlo, tenerlo cerca y hablarle.

Según [esta otra página](http://www.inspirulina.com/el-objeto-transicional-objeto-de-consuelo-o-de-apego.html), también se le puede llamar "objeto de consuelo" u "objeto de apego", que no es tan técnico y tiene algo más de la semántica de "*lovey*".

Comment: Esta es la mejor respuesta, sin desmerecer a las otras publicadas, ya que destaca que el objeto material puede ser (casi) cualquier cosa, no solo un peluche o mantita.

Answer (score 5):

En español (al menos en España) se usa la palabra *dudú*, adaptación del francés *doudou*.

> Un doudou o dudú es un pequeño trapito de motivos infantiles que muchos bebés y no tan bebés utilizan al dormir. [...] A veces puede resultar una muy buena solución a los despertares del peque durante la noche, ayudando a que se sienta tan reconfortado como si mamá o papá estuvieran con él. [...] La palabra originaria doudou es francesa y es una especie de adjetivo afectuoso, algo así como llamar a alguien “cariño”. La castellanización del doudou sería dudú y como en Francia, se usa para llamar a ese pequeño trapito, de tela aterciopelada la mayoría de veces y cabeza blandita de muñeco.
>
> [Fuente](http://www.mundobebes.net/blog/que-es-un-doudou-o-dudu/).

No la busquéis en la RAE que no está.

Answer (score 5):

En Chile a ese objeto le decimos **tuto**, aunque la palabra solo la recogen con ese significado en el [Wikcionario](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/tuto):

> Objeto al que un bebé tiene apego y requiere tener a su lado para quedarse dormido.

En la [RAE](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=tuto) en cambio especifican que se trata de una almohadilla para dormir el bebé, pero me consta que puede ser cualquier objeto, para cualquier edad y no necesariamente para dormir.

Se supone que proviene de *tuta*, palabra quechua (una lengua andina) que significa "oscuridad" y "noche", y de la cual viene otra expresión chilena: *hacer tuto*, que significa dormir. Pero después de leer la respuesta de @Carlos Alejo me sorprende la similitud con *dudú* y sospecho que la etimología puede venir por ahí.

Comment: En algunas zonas de Bolivia, al mandar a dormir a los más pequeños le decimos: "Hacer tutú"...